# "However" vs. "on the contrary"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, conjunctions

I would like to get some advice on the difference in meaning between the following sentences.

> - It is true that there have been great advances in technology over the last forty years. especially the use of mobile phones and e-mail communication are common these days. **However**, machines that translate from one language to another are still in their early stages.
> - It is true that there have been great advances in the technology over the last forty years. especially the use of mobile phones and e-mail communication are common these days. **On the contrary**, machines that translate from one language to another are still in their early stages.

Comment: Kltis, this is something that you can find out by looking up the definitions, so it's out of scope for this site. May I suggest you try English Language Learners (ell.stackexchange.com) instead? It would be a great question there!

Comment: Yes try http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/however and http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+contrary . However, I wouldn't label your strings here as 'conjunctions' - I'd label them 'pragmatic markers' subclass 'sentence connectors' for 'however' and possibly 'antiparallel statement markers' (a forceful comment by the speaker / writer is involved here) for 'on the contrary'. See the article at http://esl.about.com/od/writingintermediate/a/w_connectors.htm and follow the links for subsubclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a usage//style standpoint, I would argue that the first use (however) is correct.

The second use results in a contradiction, because you are saying 'it is true... on the contrary'.

Each has been used properly as a conjunction, combining two complex ideas into one argument. The word 'however' does not negate the preceding statement(s); by using it you are saying that the statement may be true, but you would like to direct the argument to a more important concept.

Your second conjunction... 'on the contrary'... is used to negate a preceding statement entirely. For example:

> Some say that the most important meal of the day is breakfast, because it allows the body to digest food early in the day and thus boosts metabolism. On the contrary, I believe dessert to be the most important meal of the day, because ice cream is amazing.
>
> Many claim that there have been great advances in the technology over the last forty years, pointing to the widespread use of mobile phones and e-mail communication. On the contrary, I believe that technology has a lot of opportunities ahead; machines that translate from one language to another are still in their early stages.

Comment: I just made up both examples, and the logic for each is very shoddy. These are simply intended for demonstrating the use of 'on the contrary' as a conjunction.

Answer (score 1):

If one thinks of the conversation as a vector proceeding along some line of thought,
both *However,* and *On the contrary,* (**with** commas, indicating intonation dips)
indicate that the vector (and thus the conversation) is changing direction.
But they do it in different ways.

- *However,* is general and simply announces that a topic change is coming up.
  This could be any change, in any direction, including full reverse ("180 degrees"),
  but not limited to any specific vector.

  - *He arrived early. **However**, she was there early to pick him up, so that's all right.*
  - *He arrived early. **However**, there's something else I want to talk to you about.*
  - *They said he arrived early. **However**, they were mistaken.*
  - *They said he arrived early. **However**, he was two hours late.*
- *On the contrary,* is specifically limited to full reverse.
  It can't refer to any new topic; it's restricted to changing the sign on a vector.
  It means that some proposition that has been said before is about to be contradicted.
  And the proposition is unlikely to be one advanced by the speaker,
  unless they're quoting somebody else.

  - **Q:** *Bill arrived early, didn't he?*
    **A:** *On the contrary, he was two hours late.*
  - *They told me he was early; on the contrary, he was late.*